# How to read the "IDLE" column in the output of the Linux 'w' command?

Tags: linux, utilities, command-line-interface

I'm trying to figure out a process that monitors users sessions on a remote server and alerts them when they are being idle too long, which with the Linux command `w` is aptly appropriate.

Problem is - `w` uses 3 different formats to specify the idle time of the session, and I can't figure them out properly. An output of `w` might look like this:

```
 11:40:57 up 400 days, 10:46, 13 users,  load average: 5.07, 5.10, 4.83
USER     TTY      FROM           LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
john     pts/1    XX.XX.XX.XX   Wed13   22:29m  0.13s  0.04s ssh master-db
june     pts/2    XX.XX.XX.XX   Wed13   46.00s  0.67s  0.13s -bash
jenn     pts/4    XX.XX.XX.XX   11:13   27:47   4.16s  0.11s -bash
```

As you can see, IDLE has different formats for each of the users:

- "AA.BBs" obviously means that AA seconds and BB 1/100ths of a second (46 seconds in the case of June) has passed since she was last active on the console.
- "AA:BBm" probably means that AA hours and BB minutes have passed since John was last active on his session.
- "AA:BB" is the format I can't figure out - how long has Jennifer not being active in her session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Without a qualifier, it means MM:SS -- that is, minutes and whole seconds.  As an added bonus, there's a fourth format you don't have in that output -- a number of days (NNdays) of inactivity.

Answer (score 10):

From the man page

> The standard format is DDdays, HH:MMm, MM:SS or SS.CC if the times  are
>         greater than 2 days, 1hour, or 1 minute respectively.

so your output is MM:SS (>1m and <1 hour).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is 27minutes and 47seconds

1. default format is MM:SS.
2. 22:29m means 22 hours and 29 minutes
3. 46.00s means 46 seconds
4. 4d means 4 days

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the answer to your question, but an easier approach to checking the idle time of login sessions would be to look at `/dev/pts`.  The modification times of the files in there reflect the last time the login session received input.

You should be able to do stat operations there (e.g., `stat --format="%n %X" *`), and keep everything in epoch seconds.  Should make any time calculations easier.

To obtain current time epoch in seconds you can use `date +%s`.

Comment: If you find yourself parsing time formats, you might want to look for a source of that timestamp in epoch time.

Comment: I read something about that, but I've noticed that the idle times reported by `w` are different then the timestamps on the `/dev/pts` files. any idea why?

Comment: In what context is it different?  I haven't looked at this carefully, but "w" must be pulling the information from someplace, and /dev/pts is an obvious place.  Ah, maybe if something happens on the screen (/dev/pts/* should be 2-way communications); in that case, the user would be idle, but, because of something going across the device, /dev/pts/0 for example would be updated.

Comment: That is a likely explanation, and it will defeat my scheme - because I want to shut down idle sessions even if the user is tailing some active log file or using `watch`.